# images not found because `/` its added at the end of the URL

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

(Meteor) So I was working in my project and I realized that if you navigate to `http://localhost:3000/signup` in my application everything works fine, but if you go to `http://localhost:3000/signup/` all my images are not found (url its broke), I just added the `/` at the end of the url, I would like to know how to solve this, I don't know if this is relate to `iron-router` or to Meteor. Im just using a really simple route code:

```
Router.route('/signup',function(){
    users.init();
    this.render('signupUser');       
});
```

I wanna solve it because I can see people writing the url on the browser nav input and adding the `/` at the end of the url. I know you can solve it via redirect (which I dont want to do it, cause I have to validate all my others links as well), so how to solve it? why its this happening?

-- EDIT --
I know that I could solve the problem with `location.href` I did something similar to solve the problem of the `//` on the homepage.

```
if(window.location.pathname === "//"){
    location.href = "/";
}
```

I dont think this is a good way to solve this problem. suggestion accept.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your url `src` attribute doesn't start with a forward slash right? Most surely that's the problem.

If a path does not start with a slash is considered relative

Comment: Actually my path its `http://localhost:3000/signup` without the slash and work perfect, I think should be a way that both paths, with or without the slash work.

Comment: `src=/signup/<imagename>` should be enough having your images at the `public` directory. And yes, of course you could do what you are saying but the actual files should then be served inside `public/signup` the should exists there is what I'm saying. Though it might be a better solution I don't have knowledge of

Comment: but, thats no the idea behind Meteor, Meteor at the moment you have everything on the public folder you should be able to use it, I dont think adding `signup` before the `<image-name>` its a good idea, break completely the idea of the public folder. I have my images in the public folder btw.

Comment: If you have them already on the public folder then it should make no difference in my opinion.